# Potential difference inside charge distributions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity, gauss-law

Always when I think about potential difference inside a symmetrical charge distribution, I think of it being equal to zero because it's dependent on the field and I imagine the directions of each of the tiny dE's canceling each other making the net field zero at a point.

E.g. imagine that we have a charged ring - not actually inside a charge distribution but the principle is the same - and we want to know the potential at it's center. If you asked me I'd say that since the dE's from the tiny dQ's cancel each other making $E(r=0)=0{V\over m}$ you don't have any potential.

But the right answer is that because potential is a scalar, it doesn't matter that they cancel each other and the potential at the center of the charged ring can found with $$V={kQ\over r}$$

I know it's a scalar, but it's actually calculated from vectors so obviously directions are important(in my point view). Can someone please explain this better?

Comment: Of course only by thinking that potential is work per unit charge needed to go from A to B I get the idea that potential is not just about two points but more about the path between those two points and the electric field in that path.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of potential difference is the amount of work per unit charge to move a charged particle from one place to the another place. The potential difference between point $a$ and point $b$ is as below,
$$ V_a - V_b = - \int_{\mathbf{r}_b}^{\mathbf{r}_a} \mathbf{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}.$$
What we call as potential with $V=\frac{kQ}{r}$ is the amount of work per unit charge to bring the particle from infinitely far to a distance $r$. Even though the electric field is zero at some point, it doesn't mean the potential at that point is also zero.

Back to the ring problem. Suppose that we want to bring a charged particle (e.g. electron, proton, etc) from infinitely far away to the centre of the ring along the ring's axis. Along the axis, the particle experiences electric field. Thus, we need some work* to bring the particle get closer to the centre. Non-zero work to bring it to the centre means the potential at the centre of the ring is not zero.

NB: *the work we give can be positive or negative, depends on the charge signs.

Comment: you meant 'Even though the electric field is zero at some point' not 'Even though the electric field is not zero at some point'

Comment: yes! thanks for spotting this. I have made the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in stating that potential and hence potential differences are dependent on field. The relation in fact is

> $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$

Hence, as we can see, if $E$ = 0, then $\nabla V$ is in fact constant, *not $V$*.

Now, to compute the potential, we can rely on coloumb's formula, taking $V$ at infinity t be zero,

> for a differential charge, $dq$, $dV = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r}$ at a point  a distance $r$ away from the differential charge.

Hence, the total potential is, taking V at infinity to be zero,

> $V = \int\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r} \int dq = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} = \frac{kQ}{r}$

Now, the above formula can be derived from the electric field vectors, as follows,

> $dV = -\int d\mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = -\int \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r^3} \mathbf{r} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = -\frac{dq}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\mathbf{e_r}} {r^2} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r} + C$

And taking $V$ at infinity to be zero as is conventional, we get

> $dV = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r}$

Hence, potentials are derived from field vectors, but not in the way you thought.

Comment: why $r^3$ in $-\int{1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}{dq\over r^3}\mathbf r\cdot d\mathbf r$

Comment: So that the magnitude of the force will be $\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r^2}$, and the direction will be in the direction of the position vector. The $r^3$ cancels with the magnitude of the $\mathbf{r}$ vector to get the maginitude $\frac{1}{r^2}$ and the direction of the $\mathbf{r}$ vector.